# Connect internal Macintosh HD (MacBook Pro SSD) to a Notebook running Windows via USB cable so I can format the disk?

Tags: windows, mac, formatting, high-definition

Is it possible? I forgot my MacbookPro without the electrical cable sleeping, the next day i got the blinking question folder, already have tried barely all (ALL) solutions on the internet to repair the disk, and the only option left is try formatting and repairing the disk trough Windows (because DiskUtility, Terminal, Single User Mode, etc, etc does not help)

Why I want to do this? Because I can see my files on the disk so I think there is no need to open the macbook to take out the HD etc... thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or why you think you should use Windows to do anything with a Mac drive.

Answer (score 1):

Windows' idea of "formatting" is very different from MacOS's. Formatting the disk under Windows will make all of your files inaccessible. So I think you do not really want to do that.

Comment: In fact I need to use windows repair tools to fix the disk, after fixed I will format in MAC OSX file system.

Comment: What "Windows repair tools" are you talking about? MacOS' file system structure is completely unknown to Windows. The result of fomatting the disk under Windows will be a Windows-formatted disk with no files on it. After you then format it under Mac OS X, it will _still_ have no files on it. The file system structure that defined where your files are, their names, etc., will all be gone.

Comment: Yes! That's the idea, because I have tried all possible ways of formatting on Mac and it does not work. But I can see files, etc, so I think the SSD is not broken, but Mac tools cannot repair. That's why as a last chance I want to format on Windows and them reformat on Mac. There is no problem on erasing my files, because I made a backup. So, it's possible to plug an USB cable on my Mac to a PC and read the Macintosh HD on Windows or not? Or I will have to open my Macbook, pull out the SSD, buy as SSD enclosure so I can plug the USB on a Windows?